# CSS : text-align:justify doesn't work in textarea for Internet Explorer

Tags: css, textarea, text-align, justify

text-align:justify in textarea doesn't work in Internet explorer. Here the source code, very simple :

```
<textarea style="width:500px;height:100px;white-space:pre-line;text-align:justify;"></textarea>
```

When I type some text in textarea, text-align:justify doesn't work.

Have you a solution ?

Thank you in advance, cordially.

Comment: Which version of IE are you experiencing this in?

Comment: Internet explorer 10 and edge.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `white-space: pre-line;`
Remove it and it should work.